# How to remove random integer from list that is greater than specific value in python?

Tags: python, list, random, integer

I have a list :

```
a = [1,3,5,657,78,43,7,2,123, 43, 321, 4531]
```

I would like to remove 1 random integer from this list which is greater than 100. How to do this?

Comment: c'mon man, you know the drill - you have to at least try something first :)

Comment: Choose a random index. Is the number greater than 100? If so, remove the integer. Otherwise, repeat the steps.

Comment: @VincentSavard: that could be potentially non-terminating

Comment: I know i can do it with if/while loops, but I want to know if there is a standard library function to do this.

Comment: a library function to remove list elements that exceed a threshold?  sounds rather esoteric and of limited applicability

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Of course, it's up to alwbtc to tweak it. I don't think the comments is the right place to give a long and working algorithm, but if you grasp the idea behind it (which is quite simple), I think it's easy to find a working algorithm. You could also find all number > 100 and pick an index from this set instead, it's essentially the same thing I'm saying.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want this - all elements I can deal with, one *random* element meeting a criteria, why - ie, what's the difference between 123,456,789 and 101?

Comment: @JonClements: Possibly, "lightning strikes an orc with too much HP, killing it". Of course, that's just speculation on my part

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Lightning doesn't auto-kill, it just does level d6 damage. So that's `a[random.choice([i for i,num in enumerate(a) if num>100])] -= sum(random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(caster_level))`. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **many** numbers superior to 100 in your list, you can just choose one index between the start and the end of the list, then delete it if it's superior to 100, else pick another one.

If you **don't have many items** superior to 100, you should save the elements superior to 100 in an array, choose one of them randomly, then delete it from your original array.

Comment: I think your answer is the best because you are the cutest, thanks.

Comment: wow - who's with me to start `stackoverflowdating.com`? ;)

Comment: @JonClements You should try that idea on Area 51, I'm sure you'll be very successful :D

Answer (score 8):

```
In [55]: a
Out[55]: [1, 3, 5, 657, 78, 43, 7, 2, 123, 43, 321]

In [56]: a = [1,3,5,657,78,43,7,2,123, 43, 321, 4531]

In [57]: a.pop(random.choice([i for i,num in enumerate(a) if num>100]))
Out[57]: 4531

In [58]: a
Out[58]: [1, 3, 5, 657, 78, 43, 7, 2, 123, 43, 321]
```

Comment: In `[101, 2, 101]`, this would always remove the first element.

Comment: @phihag: I hope by "first element" you mean "element at index 1". And in your case, yes; but only because 200 is the only value that's greater than 100 in `[1, 200, 1]`

Comment: Why not just grab the indexes and use `random.choice` on them? As @phihag says, that way only works when there's no repeating numbers above 100

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- I think that what phihag is alluding to is the fact that `list.remove` always pulls out the first element it finds with a particular value.  You have no way of removing the second `101` from the proposed list.

Comment: Oh! You're absolutely right! I hadn't thought of that. Updating answer

Comment: Of course, it  is as easy as changing your `dels` to `[i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x>100]` and then `a.pop` instead of `a.remove`.

Comment: @mgilson: lol! That's exactly what I just did.

Answer (score 3):

First, get a list of the indices of all elements over 100:

```
dels = [i for i, val in enumerate(a) if val > 100]
```

Now pick one from that list:

```
index = random.choice(dels)
```

Now delete that index from the original list:

```
del a[index]
```

Putting it all together:

```
>>> a = [1,3,5,657,78,43,7,2,123, 43, 321, 4531]
>>> dels = [i for i, val in enumerate(a) if val > 100]
>>> index = random.choice(dels)
>>> del a[index]
>>> a
[1, 3, 5, 657, 78, 43, 7, 2, 43, 321, 4531]
```

Comment: Some reason I always forget about `del` to remove elements from lists.  I seem to always fall back on `pop` and I'm not sure why ...

Comment: Sure, you took my answer and added code ;)  I just figured if he couldn't put the initial effort to try and post code, the best solution I could give was an algorithmic description.

Comment: @mgilson: Well, it really doesn't matter that much. It's not like C++, where an unnecessary copy can be 90% of your CPU time…

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I think we started writing at the same time, and you got your answer in 5 minutes ahead of me because it's only one line… Anyway, I was guessing that the kind of person who asks a question like this is very likely to not know about `enumerate`, and try to implement things with a `for i in range(len(a))` loop…

Comment: @abarnert - I get it, I just loathe giving it up too easily - effort expended equals prize rewarded :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: In general, sure, but when you're trying to guide someone to something they didn't even know how to ask for yet… well, I guess you could say something like "Create a list of the indices whose corresponding values are over 100 (hint: see `enumerate`), …", but that's actually much harder to write than either of the two extremes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of the index of the integers over 100, pick one of those indices at random then remove that index from the list